# Поменять местами блоки в родительскому Grid?

Tags: css, grid

Как поменять местами два последних блока. Тоесть сначала Header, за ним Info, Slider

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 24px;
  grid-template-columns: 383px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Header</div>
  <div>Slider</div>
  <div>Info</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Очень просто: выбрать предпоследний  элемент и сделать его последним при помощи положительного значения свойства order: `.main > div:nth-last-child(2) { order:1 }`

Comment: Это слишком вычурно, можно просто поменять их местами  в html разметке =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите эти два элемента и поменяйте их местами в html разметке =)

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 24px;
  grid-template-columns: 383px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Header</div>
  <div>Info</div>
  <div>Slider</div>
</div>
```